# Get Information From windows server

Tags: .net, vb.net, network-programming

Is it possible to get the incoming/outgoing bytes and frames log on time and idle time from windows remote desktop service manager ?

If you going into remote desktop service manager and you right click on a user and select status you can see a bunch of information about the user. How can i take that information when my application starts up?